# Proxy ended 404

Tags: angular

I have a working `proxy.conf.js`

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = 
[
    // working
    {
        context: 
        [
            "/path1",      
            "/path2"
        ],
        "target" : "https://localhost:3001", 

        "changeOrigin": true,       
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "logLevel": "debug",        
        "rejectUnauthorzied": true, 
        "secure": false,            
        "strictSSL": true,          
        "withCredentials": true     
    }
]
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

so `https://localhost:4200/path1` hits `https://localhost:3001/path1`, etc.

Now append a new entry for a new API backend for new feature

```
,{
    context: 
    [
        "https://localhost:4200/new/feature"
    ],
    "target" : " http://localhost:7071/az/feature", // non-SSL for testing

    "changeOrigin": true,       
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "logLevel": "debug",        
    "rejectUnauthorzied": false, 
    "secure": false,            
    "strictSSL": false,          
    "withCredentials": true     
}
```

`return this.http.post<any[]>('https://localhost:4200/new/feature', param);` error:

```
message:'Http failure response for https://localhost:4200/new/feature: 404 Not Found'
name:'HttpErrorResponse'
ok:false
status:404
statusText:'Not Found'
url:'https://localhost:4200/new/feature'
```

Comment: Why did you go for an absolute url in your context for the second one..?

Comment: @MikeOne Tried `https://localhost:4200/new/feature` yielding the same